# Mysql INSTR help search only 1 row that match more text

Tags: mysql, string, sql-order-by, where-clause, sql-limit

I have a table room with a field code

```
code
BED 6 
BED 6 DEM
```

I have a text to search like  '... BED 6 DEM ...'

If I do  `SELECT * FROM room  WHERE INSTR('... BED 6 DEM ...',code) >0`

I get these 2 rows:

```
code
BED 6 
BED 6 DEM
```

But I would like to get only 1: `BED 6 DEM`

Sometime I just need `SELECT * FROM room  WHERE INSTR('... BED 6 ...',code) >0`

and get just 1 row

```
code
BED 6
```

with is ok

Any suggestion to get always just the best match row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the results by descending length of the matched string and get the first result only:

```
SELECT *
FROM room r 
WHERE INSTR('... BED 6 DEM ...', code) > 0
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(code) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Another option is to use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery to match on longuest that contains the searched string, like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM room r 
WHERE INSTR('... BED 6 DEM ...', code) > 0
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM room r1
    WHERE 
        INSTR('... BED 6 DEM ...', r1.code) > 0
        AND CHAR_LENGTH(r1.code) > CHAR_LENGTH(r.code)
)
```

Comment: I like the first one @GMB Is Genius! Thanks! :-)